# PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I initiated pyspark in cmd and performed below to sharpen my skills.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>SUCCESS: The process with PID 5328 (child process of PID 4476) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 4476 (child process of PID 1092) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 1092 (child process of PID 3952) has been terminated.
pyspark
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/01/08 20:07:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022 19:58:39)
Spark context Web UI available at http://Mohit:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1673188677388).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> 23/01/08 20:08:10 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
a = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

When I execute a.take(1), I get "_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range" error and I am unable to find why. When same is run on google colab, it doesn't throw any error. Below is what I get in console.

```
>>> a.take(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 458, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 602, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 692, in reducer_override
    return self._function_reduce(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 565, in _function_reduce
    return self._dynamic_function_reduce(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 546, in _dynamic_function_reduce
    state = _function_getstate(func)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 157, in _function_getstate
    f_globals_ref = _extract_code_globals(func.__code__)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 334, in _extract_code_globals
    out_names = {names[oparg]: None for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 334, in <dictcomp>
    out_names = {names[oparg]: None for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
                 ~~~~~^^^^^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 458, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 602, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 692, in reducer_override
    return self._function_reduce(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 565, in _function_reduce
    return self._dynamic_function_reduce(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 546, in _dynamic_function_reduce
    state = _function_getstate(func)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 157, in _function_getstate
    f_globals_ref = _extract_code_globals(func.__code__)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 334, in _extract_code_globals
    out_names = {names[oparg]: None for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 334, in <dictcomp>
    out_names = {names[oparg]: None for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
                 ~~~~~^^^^^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1883, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 1486, in runJob
    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 3505, in _jrdd
    wrapped_func = _wrap_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 3362, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 3345, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 468, in dumps
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

It should provide [1] as an answer but instead throws this error. Is it because of incorrect installation?

Package used - spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_351-b10), Python 3.11.1

Can anyone help in troubleshooting this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be python version incompatible issue, can you recheck with version `3.8`?

Comment: I tried with Python 3.8.5 and now it shows a different error which Java IO Exception though I pip installed py4j with JDK already installed.

Comment: I have the same bug. Python 3.11.1

Comment: I fixed downgrading to Python 3.9, then I installed pip in the version 3.9 doing `python3.9 -m ensurepip` and then you can use with `python3.9 -m pip install pyspark`. after that you will get an error which says you are running pyspark 3.9 with python 3.11.... it's a environment variable problem, you have to change two variables:

Comment: I use jupyter lab in vscode so in order to have the right variables in vs code jupyterlab you have to open jupyter lab extension settings.json and put `"jupyter.runStartupCommands": [
        "import os\nos.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']='/bin/python3.9'\nos.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON']='/bin/python3.9/'\n"
    ]`

Comment: if you want to use pyspark with python 3.9 in all the system instead, you can add in .bashrc `export PYSPARK_PYTHON='/bin/python3.9'` and `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON='/bin/python3.9'`

Comment: I wish to use pyspark in Jupyter Notebook in Windows 10. I have already set environment variables for Python 3.8.5, Spark, Hadoop and JRE in control panel. It throws Java IO Exception when executive take function of RDD. I believe I have installed it correctly. Can you troubleshoot that? @Allexj

Comment: @Allexj Thank you for the solution. It still does not work when I try to run Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 13):

According to https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/38987 you will need Spark 3.4.0 to use Python 3.11, at the time of writing not yet released at https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html. Python 3.10 should work.

Comment: I even tried with Python 3.8.5, but same error persists. I ran standalone Spark in cmd and it works without a flaw and gives the correct output. I am running 2 versions of Python i.e. 3.8.5 and 3.11.1 with 3.8.5 set as default. It throws same error as it did. Any corrections to follow?

Comment: @MohitAswani To ensure you are absolutely not using Python 3.11 I would uninstall it completely and then see what happens, as you could have other environment variables or configuration in Spark that still point to 3.11 instead of 3.8.

Answer (score 9):

As of 3/2/23, I had the same identical problem, and as indicated above, I uninstalled python 3.11 and installed version 3.10.9 and it's solved!

Comment: I have just installed Python 3.10.11 in addition to 3.11.x and used 3.10 as the base interpreter for the venv with PySpark 3.4 and Spark 3.4.0 server. 
It works seamlessly too.